# CASE WHEN PARA UN SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta tabla que se llama `SI_Consecutivo`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que estoy tratado de realizar es que si `SI_Estado = 0` y `SI_Num_Conteo = 2`

Me haga esta consulta

```
SELECT 
SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo), 
SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion), 
SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''), 
SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica), 
SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
/*SI_Cantidad2 = (SELECT COALESCE(c2.SI_Cantidad,0)  
FROM SI_Conteo c2 
WHERE  c2.SI_Num_Conteo = 2 AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c2.SI_Ubicacion), */
SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
full JOIN SI_Conteo c 
ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo  
AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion  
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m  
ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
WHERE 
(c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 OR t.SI_Articulo = 201533)
AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 2)
```

y si no 
me haga esta otra

```
SELECT 
SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo), 
SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion), 
SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''), 
SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica), 
SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
/*SI_Cantidad2 = (SELECT COALESCE(c2.SI_Cantidad,0)  
FROM SI_Conteo c2 
WHERE  c2.SI_Num_Conteo = 2 AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c2.SI_Ubicacion), */
SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
full JOIN SI_Conteo c 
ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo  
AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion  
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m  
ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
WHERE 
(c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 OR t.SI_Articulo = 201533)
AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1
```

Yo lo estaba realizando de esta manera pero no me funciona.
Me da el siguiente error

> Sólo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección
>   cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS.

```
SELECT SI_Estado, SI_Num_Conteo,
(CASE WHEN SI_Estado = 0 and SI_Num_Conteo = 2 THEN 
(SELECT 
SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo), 
SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion), 
SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''), 
SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica), 
SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
/*SI_Cantidad2 = (SELECT COALESCE(c2.SI_Cantidad,0)  
FROM SI_Conteo c2 
WHERE  c2.SI_Num_Conteo = 2 AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c2.SI_Ubicacion), */
SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
full JOIN SI_Conteo c 
ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo  
AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion  
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m  
ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
WHERE 
(c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 OR t.SI_Articulo = 201533)
AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 2)
ELSE
(SELECT 
SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo), 
SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion), 
SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''), 
SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica), 
SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
/*SI_Cantidad2 = (SELECT COALESCE(c2.SI_Cantidad,0)  
FROM SI_Conteo c2 
WHERE  c2.SI_Num_Conteo = 2 AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c2.SI_Ubicacion), */
SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
full JOIN SI_Conteo c 
ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo  
AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion  
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m  
ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
WHERE 
(c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 OR t.SI_Articulo = 201533)
AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1)
END)
FROM SI_Consecutivo
```

Comment: Consejo amistoso: por favor no pongas el título de tus preguntas en mayúscula y ofrece un poco mas de información en el mismo. Respecto a tu pregunta: ¿hay alguna posibilidad de cambiar la forma en que haces tu consulta para dividir la lógica?

Comment: Que tal Eduard, por lo que veo sigues con esas tablas, que necesitas mostrar? parece que tu pregunta apunta a que por las condiciones de los joins, el resultado es diferente vdd? otra cosa SI_Estado = 0, por lo que veo es necesario en el where.

Comment: Si, puede cambiar la forma de la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, el case when se usa para devolver un dato como tal no para ejecutar alguna secuencia por eso debes de usar if else

quedaria algo asi:

```
SELECT SI_Estado, SI_Num_Conteo,
    (IF SI_Estado = 0 and SI_Num_Conteo = 2
    begin
        SELECT 
            SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo), 
            SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion), 
            SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''), 
            SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica), 
            SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
            SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
            /*SI_Cantidad2 = (SELECT COALESCE(c2.SI_Cantidad,0)  
                FROM SI_Conteo c2 
                WHERE  c2.SI_Num_Conteo = 2 AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c2.SI_Ubicacion), */
            SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
            SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)
        FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
            full JOIN SI_Conteo c ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo  
                AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion  
            INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m  ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
                OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
        WHERE 
            (c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 OR t.SI_Articulo = 201533)
                AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 2)
    end
ELSE
    begin
        SELECT 
            SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo), 
            SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion), 
            SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''), 
            SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica), 
            SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
            SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
            /*SI_Cantidad2 = (SELECT COALESCE(c2.SI_Cantidad,0)  
            FROM SI_Conteo c2 
            WHERE  c2.SI_Num_Conteo = 2 AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c2.SI_Ubicacion), */
            SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
            SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)
        FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
            full JOIN SI_Conteo c ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo  
                AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion  
            INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m  ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
                OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
        WHERE 
            (c.SI_Num_Articulo = 201533 OR t.SI_Articulo = 201533)
                AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1
    end
)
FROM SI_Consecutivo
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que ambos querys solo cambian en la ultima condición, entonces
el case lo puedes manejar así:

```
SELECT SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo), 
       SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion), 
       SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''), 
       SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica), 
SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0), 
SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)                          
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t                   
full JOIN SI_Conteo c 
ON t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo  
AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion  
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m  
ON  t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
where (C.SI_NUM_ARTICULO = 201533 or T.SI_ARTICULO = 201533)   
and SI_NUM_CONTEO = (case SI_ESTADO when '0' then  2 else 1 end)
```

Comment: Este AND `and SI_NUM_CONTEO = (case SI_ESTADO when '0' then 2 else 1 end)` no esta haciendo nada. igual me los muestra todos.